# why are multiple '>' allowed in xml

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, w3c

Here's a "valid" XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><class>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><abc att="da"/></class>
```

I have a relatively simple question: why is this XML correctly validated by virtually all possible parsers?
I checked latest xml specs from w3.org https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/ but I cannot find anything related to this. Is this something implementation specific?

The symbol '<' cannot be used multiple times ie.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><class><<abc att="da"/></class>
```

this XML is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#syntax

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) must not appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings "&amp;" and "&lt; " respectively. The right angle bracket (>) may be represented using the string "&gt;", and must, for compatibility, be escaped using either "&gt;" or a character reference when it appears in the string "]]>" in content, when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA section.

If you have an unencoded literal `<`, then the parser will assume that you are starting an element. You can't have a sequence of them, because you can't have `<` in an element name.

If you have an unencoded literal `>`, there isn't any confusion about closing an element. It is just a sequence of `>` in the `text()` node of an element.

You can encode the `<` as `&lt;`:

```
<class>&lt;<abc att="da"/></class>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! You mean the element is 'class', it's opened with <class> and then the '>>>>...' is basically text inside it?

Comment: @SterpuMihai yes, exactly